# Where do I register .sh domain?

Tags: domain-registration

I want to register a personal domain with `sh` extension. Where to register? I didn't find any registrar. I will use this for my personal blog and portfolio. I didn't have any organisation or any company. I reside in India if it helps

Comment: If this answered your questions please mark it as the answer

Comment: why is this domain extension so costly?

Comment: Registrars can set their own pricing above the NIC fee's handling that TLD

Comment: Just a warning, it seems kind of randomly they will revoke a domain name if it even seems like it could be remotely provocative, without asking the person who registered it. They usually refund for that, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.nic.sh/registrars.html

Comment: I registered directly through nic.sh - they seem rather unprofessional sometimes.